# I am trying to restrict Azure NSG outbound internet traffic and allow only traffic for ubuntu updates for a VM. Do we have static IP for update server

Tags: updates, ip, automatic

We are checking if there is static public IP which is not changed frequently for the ubuntu automatic updates in Azure VM to configure the same in allowed outbound traffic in NSG.

Comment: Don't Azure have their own mirrors located within their cloud?

Comment: i already have raised a microsoft ticket on same. But got update from microsoft that they dont have any service tag or IPs from microsoft side. They are only working on a service tag for microsoft updates.

Comment: Hi Team, is there any update on the above request

Comment: There're no teams here.